# summary of datatypes in Emacs lisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I started reading emacs lisp intro. I haven't seen any mentioning of data types. can anyone summarize datatypes in elisp with simple examples.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lisp fundamentally only has atoms and lists. Emacs has a wealth of editor-related special objects (characters, buffers, frames, markers, processes, keymaps, etc) some of which are implemented as lists or vectors (a special kind of list) but for a general overview, strings, numbers, symbols, and lists of these are probably all you need in order to get started.

Comment: thanks.. indeed I think you summarized well for me to get start.. I see, the next step would be to know different functions that can operate on these data types.

Answer (score 7):

I would refer you to the section of the Emacs Lisp reference entitled [Lisp Data Types](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Lisp-Data-Types.html#Lisp-Data-Types).